# Wrong table format in Rstudio for csv file

Tags: r

I have recieved an excel file which converted as csv (separator - comma).

[image]

However, after I have uploaded it to R it has an incorrect format

```
wine <- read.csv("F:/forstat/WinePrices1.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

[image]

How can I clear table?

Udpate.

```
wine <- read.csv2("F:/forstat/WinePrices1.csv", sep  = ",", header = TRUE)
```

[image]

And I cant delete these columns

Comment: Look more as if a semicolon is used as separator. I would try with `sep=";"` or use read.csv2 which uses a ";" by default.

Comment: @stefan I got rid of ; but got tons of columns with NA

Comment: Yes, there's many NAs because that is what is in the file: many empty columns. If you only need the first two columns, use e.g. `wine_small <- wine[1:2]`

Comment: Always check for unused ghost cells in Excel. Find with: `Ctrl/Cmd` + `End`.